# Android, typeface not copied into new paint

Tags: android, paint, typeface

In the following code:

```
Paint tPaint = new Paint(aPaint);
tPaint.setTypeface(typeFace);
aPaint =  new Paint(tPaint);
```

typeFace is observed set into tPaint but, typeFace does not get copied into aPaint.

Comment: More code and information about android please because it´s working for me?

Comment: There really is not much more code to show. The typeFace and aPaint variables have previously been set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly an answer but a work around.

I replaced the: aPaint =  new Paint(tPaint); with: aPaint =  newPaint(tPaint); and created the method:

```
  public Paint newPaint(Paint fromPaint){
      Typeface tf = fromPaint.getTypeface();
      Paint rPaint = new Paint(fromPaint);
      rPaint.setTypeface(tf);
      return rPaint;
  }
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok that´s how my code look like. See if you can find anything.

**MainView.java**

```
public class MainView extends View {
Context context;

public MainView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint apaint = new Paint();
    apaint.setTextSize(100);
    apaint.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/sketchblock.ttf"));

    canvas.drawText("Dusean", canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2, apaint);
    Paint tpaint = new Paint(apaint);

    canvas.drawText("Dusean", canvas.getWidth()/3, canvas.getHeight()/3, tpaint);
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MainView(this));
}
}
```

and font in the Assets folder **assets/fonts/font.ttf**

Comment: I can't see any significant difference except that my code does not work.